# Количества не прочитанных сообщений

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. У меня сообщение в виде диалогов по типу контакта.Есть две таблицы первая таблица message_group там 3 поля user_one,user_two, hash и вторая таблица messages там 4 поля. id,group_hash,from_id,message. Вот скрипт на добавления сообщения в бд

```
<?php
$random_number = rand();

$check_con = mysql_query("SELECT `hash` FROM `message_group` WHERE (`user_one`='$myrow2[id]' AND `user_two`='$id') OR (`user_one`='$id' AND `user_two`='$myrow2[id]')");

if(mysql_num_rows($check_con) == 1) {
    echo "<p>Сообщение отправленно</p>";
} else
{

mysql_query("INSERT INTO message_group VALUES('$myrow2[id]','$id','$random_number')");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','$random_number','$myrow2[id]','$message')");//заносим в базу сообщение

echo "<p>Вы начали диалог с пользователем</p>";

}

?>
```

и сам вывод сообщений

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
print<<<HERE
<a href='Messages?id=$myrow2[id]' class='dialog'>Диалоги</a>

<hr><div class="parent">
<div class="div1">
HERE;
$message_query = mysql_query("SELECT from_id, message FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash'");
while ($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)) {
  $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
  $message = $run_message['message'];

     $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$from_id'");
       $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
       $from_username = $run_user['username'];
       $from_family = $run_user['family'];
       $from_avatar = $run_user['avatar'];

       echo "

       <div class='stimg'>
<img alt='аватар' src='$from_avatar'width='50px' border='0'></div>
<div class='stus'>$from_username $from_family</div>
<div class='stbody'>
<div class='sttext'>$message</div>
</div>
";

}

?>
<br/>

<form  method='post'>
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
  $new_message = $_POST['message'];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','$myrow2[id]','$new_message')");

}
  ?></div></div>
Ответить на сообщение <br/>
<textarea name='message' rows='6' cols='60'></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' id="button_send" value="Отправить"/>

</form>

<?php
<?php

} else {

echo "<h2><center>Выбрать диалог</h2></center><hr/>";
$get_con = mysql_query("SELECT `hash`, `user_one`, `user_two` FROM message_group WHERE user_one='$myrow2[id]' OR user_two='$myrow2[id]' ");
    while($run_con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)) {
  $hash = $run_con['hash'];
  $user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
  $user_two = $run_con['user_two'];

    if ($user_one == $myrow2['id']) {
      $select_id = $user_two;
    } else {

        $select_id = $user_one;
}

$user_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$select_id' ");
$run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_get);
$select_username = $run_user['username'];
$select_family = $run_user['family'];
       $select_avatar = $run_user['avatar'];

print <<<HERE
 <p><div id='messagest2'><a href='?hash=$hash'><img alt='аватар' src='$select_avatar'width='50px' border='0'> $select_username $select_family</a></div></p>
HERE;
    }

}

?>
```

Вот мне нужно сделать например пользователь 1 написал пользователю 2 и у пользователя 2 высветилось типа +1. Пробовал вставлять например activ в каждую из групп не работал совсем даже не отправлял сообщение и не выводил.Помогите пожалуйста парюсь уже месяц.

Comment: @andreykartavtsev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto Спасибо большое просто не знаю как тут все еще работает новенький тут.

Answer (score 1):

заведите еще одно поле в таблице messages например is_read 0/1 или Y/N или TRUE/FALSE(BOOLEAN) и с помощью него определяйте новые не прочитаные сообщения, или как вариант заведите отдельную таблицу где храните последний ID прочитаного сообщения для каждого пользователя, соответственно все сообщения для этого пользователя с id большим чем тот что записан в таблице - будут новыми и не прочитаными

Comment: @levantez а сможете на примере показать в моем скрипте?там вроде бы еще при октытии сообщения надо делать упдейт.  не знаю куда его вставить. я понял то что нужно при заносе в бд присвоить 0 типа не прочитанное, а вот когда человек заходит в смс то делать упдейт ставить один и выводить на экран, но что то не могу додуматься как написать этот код(((